# sweep command running in postfix mail server

Tags: linux, postfix, amavis

I have installed postfix with amavis on Redhat. Also, I have configured AV scanner as well in amavis to counter mail viruses. 
  Whenever I see **top** command result, I find a lot of instances of sweep command running regularly. Whereas in amavis conf file, I have commented out sweep  config. Any help on this.